# Apache crashes when running from a path with German umlauts

Tags: apache-2.4, windows-10

When running Apache 2.4.37.0 (with PHP) on a German Windows 10, it runs successfully when having a file path to the httpd.exe without [German umlauts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_umlaut) (ä, ö, ü).

As soon as having a path component with German umlauts, Apache immediately exists with exit code 0xc0000005.

The event log has an entry with ID 1000 and the following information:

> Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: httpd.exe, Version: 2.4.37.0, Zeitstempel: 0x5bc8a3ef
>   Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: ADVAPI32.dll, Version: 10.0.18362.752, Zeitstempel: 0xcf4d11bd
>   Ausnahmecode: 0xc0000005
>   Fehleroffset: 0x0004ec89
>   ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0x595c
>   Startzeit der fehlerhaften Anwendung: 0x01d6337ccb383ddf
>   Pfad der fehlerhaften Anwendung: C:\Ablage\Müller\Packaging\ApacheWebServer\bin\httpd.exe
>   Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
>   Berichtskennung: 64199c64-5f5b-430c-9b4c-4bb900e9f3b8
>   Vollständiger Name des fehlerhaften Pakets:
>   Anwendungs-ID, die relativ zum fehlerhaften Paket ist:

Manually translated to English, this roughly reads:

> Name of the erroneous application: httpd.exe, Version: 2.4.37.0, Time stamp: 0x5bc8a3ef
>   Name of the erroneous module: ADVAPI32.dll, Version: 10.0.18362.752, Time stamp: 0xcf4d11bd
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Error offset: 0x0004ec89
>   ID of the erroneous process: 0x595c
>   Start time of the erroneous application: 0x01d6337ccb383ddf
>   Path to the erroneous application: C:\Ablage\Müller\Packaging\ApacheWebServer\bin\httpd.exe
>   Path to the erroneous module: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
>   Report id: 64199c64-5f5b-430c-9b4c-4bb900e9f3b8
>   Full name of the erroneous packet:
>   Application ID, relative to the erroneous packet:

Beside finding nothing on Google, I am completely clueless how (or whether) this is resolvable.

I've also tried to start Apache (from my C# application) via its short path syntax, but this did not change the outcome.

#### My question

How can I let Apache run on a path with German umlauts?

Comment: Where did you obtain your version of Apache?

Comment: Would you mind having a look at this: https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=8285 ?

Comment: Thanks, @GerardH.Pille I've just updated both PHP and Apache to the latest version. Issue still there, seems to be only happening when PHP is involved; Apache alone seems to work well. Will investigate more and update my question here when I find out more.

Comment: Turns out, after updating PHP and Apache and _also_ installing the latest VC++ 2019 redistributable, this fixes the issue.

Comment: Probably the reason the Google search failed.  Stupid thing always needs the correct search criteria.

Comment: Mind posting the full solution as an actual answer? Search engines like to point people to working solutions, and marking it accepted helps signal that.

Comment: What is unclear, @anx? like I commented above, I installed [latest PHP](https://windows.php.net/download/), [latest Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#down) and [latest VC++ 2019 redistributables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads). I'll put this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As of request, here is [my above comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/1018779/apache-crashes-when-running-from-a-path-with-german-umlauts?noredirect=1#comment1323016_1018779) as an answer)

The following steps helped me:

1. I installed the [latest PHP](https://windows.php.net/download/)
2. I installed the [latest Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#down)
3. I installed the [latest VC++ 2019 redistributables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

After that, the error was not present anymore.

See also [this related discussion](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=8285) on Apache Lounge.